# Unity5 - Click to Move script not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello Ive used this script in my 2.5D iso perspective multiplayer game and did not get it to work. I thought it may be because of the multiplayerunet component I used. Any ideas where the problem could be? I am using this code on the multiplayer example project from Unity/Unet. Even just a hint would be highly appreciated

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[DisallowMultipleComponent]
public class PlayerControlerCTM : MonoBehaviour{
    [SerializeField][Range(1,20)]
    private float speed = 10;
    private Vector3 targetPosition;
    private bool isMoving;

    const int LEFT_MOUSE_BUTTON = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        targetPosition = transform.position;
        isMoving = false; 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (!isLocalPlayer)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(LEFT_MOUSE_BUTTON))
        {
            SetTargetPosition();
        }

        if(isMoving)
        {
            MovePlayer();
        }
    }

    void SetTargetPosition()
    {
        Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        float point = 0f;

        if(plane.Raycast(ray, out point))
        {
            targetPosition = ray.GetPoint(point);
        }
    }

    void MovePlayer()
    {
        transform.LookAt(targetPosition);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(transform.position == targetPosition)
        {
            isMoving = false;
        }

        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, targetPosition, Color.red);
    }
}
```

Comment: "You" are the one who tells where the problem is. "We" help you to solve it. :)

Comment: Why is this PlayerControlerCTM  thing a MonoBehaviour, and not a NetworkBehaviour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your player ain't moving because you never change the value of **isMoving** which you've set **false**.
Try this:

```
void SetTargetPosition()
{
     Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
     Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
     float point = 0f;

     if(plane.Raycast(ray, out point))
     {
         targetPosition = ray.GetPoint(point);
     }
     isMoving = true; // ADD THIS LINE
}
```

Comment: Thx for help!

Stupid me! Solved the problem ofc, too many lines of code for me ;)

Comment: That happens hahaha by the way, check the answer so the thread gets solved ^^